# recorrer array asociativo multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array asociativo multidimensional y no encuentro la forma de recorrerlo, siendo cada uno de los valores accesible:

```
$paises = ['espanya' => $espanya, 'usa' => "$", 'brasil' => "R$", 'canada' => "C$", 'colombia' => "COP", 'hongkong' => "HK$", 'hungria' => "HUF", 'rusia' => "R$", 'singapur' => "S$", 'sudafrica' => "ZAR", 'mexico' => "MXN", 'argentina' => "ARS"];

$espanya = ['€' => 'desc_ES'];

foreach ($paises as $pais => $moneda) {

   //código

}
```

Por ejemplo para el caso del primer valor del array `espanya` quiero acceder a `espanya`, `€` y `desc_ES`. ¿Es eso posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, entiendo que la definición es al revés: primero defines `$espanya` y después `$paises`. De lo contrario, el valor `'espanya' => $espanya` no se convertirá correctamente.

```
$espanya = ['€' => 'desc_ES'];

$paises = ['espanya' => $espanya, 'usa' => "$", 'brasil' => "R$", 'canada' => "C$", 'colombia' => "COP", 'hongkong' => "HK$", 'hungria' => "HUF", 'rusia' => "R$", 'singapur' => "S$", 'sudafrica' => "ZAR", 'mexico' => "MXN", 'argentina' => "ARS"];
```

Dicho lo cual, si lo que quieres es circular sobre un array multidimensional, debes utilizar un bucle para cada nivel: uno para los países y otro para el contenido de cada uno de los valores. Así, yo haría:

```
foreach ($paises as $nombre => $valor) {
   foreach ($valor as $moneda => $desc) {
       print "el pais es $nombre, la moneda $moneda y descr $desc.<br />\n";
   }
}
```

Que te devolverá algo así como:

```
el pais es espanya, la moneda € y descr desc_ES.<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira me tope con algo parecido a lo tuyo en cierta ocasion, y esta seria otra solucion al problema.

```
$paises = [array('€' => 'desc_ES'), 'usa' => "$", 'brasil' => "R$", 'canada' => "C$", 'colombia' => "COP", 'hongkong' => "HK$", 'hungria' => "HUF", 'rusia' => "R$", 'singapur' => "S$", 'sudafrica' => "ZAR", 'mexico' => "MXN", 'argentina' => "ARS"];

foreach ($paises as $dato => $valor){
    if (is_array($valor)){
    foreach ($valor as $moneda => $desc){
    echo $moneda . " " . $desc . '<br>';
    }
    } else {
    echo $dato ." ". $valor. '<br>';
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fue suprimir el arreglo `espanya` e introducirlo directamente al arreglo paises, el unico detalle que tienes que tener en cuenta es que al momento de recorrerlo tiene que determinar si es un arreglo o no y ahi esta el truco de todo eso.